# facebook-android-sdk compatibility issue

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, android-emulator

I am using this sample application : https://github.com/prajwol/Birthday-Reminder in which they have used **old facebook-android-sdk**, but now they are pointing to Facebook android SDK 3.0 which is latest because this sample app has made 2years ago and now i want to use this app but i don't know which was the old facebook SDK and where can i get that one, or if i wish to make this program runnable with **updated facebook sdk which is 3.0** so what i need to do to make this app work able for me.

I am getting several errors related to **The import com.facebook cannot be resolved**

If i use organised imports then it will delete imports related to facebook, but it is not the thing i am looking to, because i know imports are right but they have pointed to new facebook - android - sdk 3.0 whereas app has made on old one 2 years ago and it supports old sdk, so **there is no doubt facebook-android-sdk compatibility issue creating a problem here**

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have solved your own problem. Get the new SDK and resolve the issues. If the project is not compatible with new SDK, then you'll have to find the parts that are incompatible and modify them to be compatible.

If this is too hard/not worth it, then drop the sample app and go find a sample that works with the newer SDK.

Comment: could you please guide me how can i modify incompatible parts then i will check last otherwise i will find a new sample code because you are right i have already given huge time to sort out this issue

Comment: There is no general way to do this. It is very specific to your situation and very time consuming. My advice is to drop it and move on.

Comment: friend i have tried to find some other sample code but i did not get any and this sample app 100% meet to my requirement so do you have any suggestion to make it valuable for me

Comment: Apart from trying to modify it yourself, there isn't anything I can do. You can raise an issue with the developer in the "issues" section of that github repository. Maybe he will update his sample app to be compatible with the new SDK.

Comment: thanks for comments and i have also talked with one of the finest developer who has solved lots of questions at stackoverflow and i hope he will rectify it after 9 pm, anyways thanks for help